# I want to make the task in Activity visible to the parent object of the parent

Tags: lookup, tasks, hierarchy

[image]

[image]

There is a task registered in the Contract record. Contract refers to Opportunity as Lookup. So I want to show Contract's task in the Lookup Opportunity. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce only allows activities to be linked to one object.  That said, the activities for both opportunities and contracts will be visible at the account level, as the account provides an activity overview.

It is also possible to add a lookup field to the activity object, but I'd not recommend this approach as the activity would not appear in the standard views for the new lookup.